# How do I make a looping ScrollView?

Tags: android, loops, scrollview

Like the title says, how do I make a looping scrollview? :)

In other words, when you scroll to the bottom, the scrollview should not stop and continue in the same speed from the top seamless! hope someone knows this!

Comment: There is nothing built into Android for this. You will need to create your own custom `View` class, unless somebody else has already written one for you.

Comment: The easiest way I can think of is duplicating the content (vertically), then once the user hits the second content block just translate the ScrollView up by the height of a content block. (Although you'd sort of need to have 3 content blocks for it to work scrolling upwards, and in this case you'd need to start them looking at the middle block)

Comment: @CommonsWare I know that it isnt anything for this in the sdk.

@Joseph Yes I have thought of that but I think that its a pretty dirty solution... maybe somebody knows a better way :)

Comment: The loop as you want we can work with ListView easy. But with ScrollView i think we can be do by this way: 1. Add triple view that you want to loop in a ViewGroup as LinearLayout (orient vertical) . 2. Override onScrollChanged() to detect when scroll to third subview of  viewgroup, at that point, we remove  firstview ( have been invisible) then add that view to bottom of groupview

Comment: You can modified this for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316743/detect-end-of-scrollview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can afford to use a `listView` instead of a `scrollView`, there is a [library](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/circular-list-adapter) that can turn it into a circular `listView` :

> Circular list adapter for Android's ListView. This adapter makes your existing list adapter appear circular and possibly infinite unless you scroll down through two billion list items ;). Works with list adapters that you already have. No project specific dependencies. Just include the latest jar or the sources to your Android project.

**Update:** Ooh I just noticed you asked this way back in 2011. Guess you have figured it out by now. Anyway, I'll leave this here.